# Can we further restrict the space of test functions to $C_c^\infty (X)$ in weak convergence?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $X := \mathbb R^n$,
- $C_b(X)$ the space of all real-valued bounded continuous,
- $C_c(X)$ the space of all real-valued continuous functions with compact supports, and
- $C_c^\infty(X)$ the space of all real-valued smooth functions with compact supports.

Let $\mu, \mu_n$ be Borel probability measures on $X$. We say that $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ *weakly* iff
$$
\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in C_b(X).
$$

Because $\mathbb R^n$ is locally compact and separable, we [have](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4570642/1019043)
$$
\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu \iff \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in C_c(X).
$$

> Can we further restrict the space of test functions to $C_c^\infty (X)$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: You seem to be missing some sort of tightness condition.  Suppose that $\mu_n$ is the point measure at $\{n\}$.  Then this converges to zero along $C_c$ but not along $C_b$.

Comment: @terceira It seems in your example $\mu_n := \delta_n$. Could you explain what is your $\mu$?

Comment: My $\mu$ is the zero measure.

Comment: @terceira Ah my $\mu, \mu_n$ are all probability measures.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.

Comment: This holds for probability measures because the set of probability measures is equicontinuous. Beware that on the entire space of bounded signed measures these are three distinct weak topologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any $f\in C_c(X)$ can be uniformly approximated by functions $f_n\in C_c^\infty(X)$, say by convolving $f$ with appropriate mollifiers $\psi_n\in C_c^\infty(X)$.

So, your desired conclusion indeed follows.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I have just got the same conclusion from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3609933/1019043) answer in which Stone–Weierstrass theorem is appealled.